# DC 9 V -> 7.6 V

Tags: dc-dc-converter, usb-c

I want to power my camera via a dummy battery using a portable powerbank with powerdrive.

I was thinking of using this [cord](https://www.songbirdfx.com/products/birdcord-pd9v/).

The specs for AC -> DC block that the dummy battery plugs into the mains with says 7.6 V 2 A.

How can I convert the output from the 9 V cable accordingly?

Comment: What is a dummy battery?

Comment: @Andyaka A dummy battery is a replacement battery pack for a device which powers the device from some other source like mains power supply instead of actual battery.

Comment: Buck converter or a different power supply.

Comment: It depends on the tolerance of the design. 7.6V is probably a nominal voltage corresponding to 2 x 3.8V cells. However fully charged cells can have a bit higher voltage still. Unless you know how the voltage regulator in the camera is designed, there's no telling what will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a *buck converter* module on the Internet or your nearby electronic parts store which will do this without hassle. 7.6V isn't a usual output voltage, so find one with an adjustable output, then make sure to adjust it *before* you wire it to the camera (use a multimeter to see what the output voltage is). The input voltage is flexible, often 0-30V, so 9V is fine.

Before buying one do check what it says for input voltage, output voltage, and maximum current. Often they tell you a "maximum current" but they don't bother to tell you whether it's maximum input or output current, so be pessimistic and assume it's both. (Since you are decreasing the voltage you are increasing the current and therefore the output current is the higher one)

A buck converter can only decrease voltage, not increase it. If you wanted the opposite you could use a boost converter - very similar - and if you wanted both types for flexible operation you could use a buck-boost converter that combines both abilities.

Comment: thanks a lot - very helpful!